# How to search for some XML data and repleace it with a new value using Nokogiri Ruby gem

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

Base on below XML exemple file *employees.xml* and using Ruby Nokogiri gem I wan to open this file, change the building number to 320 and the room number to 99 for Sandra Defoe and save the changes. What is the recommended way to do it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<employees>
    <employee id="be129">
        <firstname>Jane</firstname>
        <lastname>Doe</lastname>
        <building>327</building>
        <room>19</room>
    </employee>
    <employee id="be130">
        <firstname>William</firstname>
        <lastname>Defoe</lastname>
        <building>326</building>
        <room>14a</room>
    </employee>
    <employee id="be132">
        <firstname>Sandra</firstname>
        <lastname>Defoe</lastname>
        <building>327</building>
        <room>22</room>
    </employee>
    <employee id="be133">
        <firstname>Steve</firstname>
        <lastname>Casey</lastname>
        <building>327</building>
        <room>24</room>
    </employee>
</employees>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is extremely broad. Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages. We appreciate that you might be new, but we do expect evidence of the effort you've put into this. Where did you search? Why didn't it help? If it did, where is the code you wrote to test what you learned? If you didn't write code, why not? If you did, what is the minimal code that demonstrates the problem you encountered, along with the explanation of the problem, and the minimal input data and the expected result? Without that it's hard to help you.

Comment: XPath selectors can look for text inside nodes; There are many questions and answers here on SO about this. I'd recommend searching for XPath's `text()` using Google, researching, and trying things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume your content is a string:

```
xml=%q(
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<employees>
    <employee id="be129">
        <firstname>Jane</firstname>
        <lastname>Doe</lastname>
        <building>327</building>
        <room>19</room>
    </employee>
    <employee id="be130">
        <firstname>William</firstname>
        <lastname>Defoe</lastname>
        <building>326</building>
        <room>14a</room>
    </employee>
    <employee id="be132">
        <firstname>Sandra</firstname>
        <lastname>Defoe</lastname>
        <building>327</building>
        <room>22</room>
    </employee>
    <employee id="be133">
        <firstname>Steve</firstname>
        <lastname>Casey</lastname>
        <building>327</building>
        <room>24</room>
    </employee>
</employees>)

doc = Nokogiri.parse(xml)
```

This will work but assumes the first and last names are unique, otherwise it will modify the first match of first and last name.

```
target = doc.css('employee').find do |node|
  node.search('firstname').text == 'Sandra' &&
  node.search('lastname').text == 'Defoe'
end

target.at_css('building').content = '320'
target.at_css('room').content = '99'

doc # outputs the updated xml
=> <?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<employees>
    <employee id="be129">
        <firstname>Jane</firstname>
        <lastname>Doe</lastname>
        <building>327</building>
        <room>19</room>
    </employee>
    <employee id="be130">
        <firstname>William</firstname>
        <lastname>Defoe</lastname>
        <building>326</building>
        <room>14a</room>
    </employee>
    <employee id="be132">
        <firstname>Sandra</firstname>
        <lastname>Defoe</lastname>
        <building>320</building>
        <room>99</room>
    </employee>
    <employee id="be133">
        <firstname>Steve</firstname>
        <lastname>Casey</lastname>
        <building>327</building>
        <room>24</room>
    </employee>
</employees>
```

Comment: I don't know the id. I have a huge xls file with employee data. I have to identyfy them by first name, last name, building and room. They moved so I have to prepare XML file with changes.

Comment: @MickLasocki that was not made clear in your question, please update accordingly

Comment: @MickLasocki see updated answer, should get what you need.

Comment: That's an awkward way to select a node based on contained text because CSS doesn't make it easy. Instead, use XPath which directly supports it. Also, please don't use "edit" or "update" tags when you modify your text. Instead, incorporate the information as if it'd been there all along. The flow of information is much more important than documenting the changes.

Comment: @theTinMan I don't see where in this code `edit` or `update` is even called.

Comment: You added it yesterday. I removed it per the community guidelines. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60727361/revisions

Answer (score 2):

I'd use this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<employees>
    <employee id="be130">
        <firstname>William</firstname>
        <lastname>Defoe</lastname>
        <building>326</building>
        <room>14a</room>
    </employee>
    <employee id="be132">
        <firstname>Sandra</firstname>
        <lastname>Defoe</lastname>
        <building>327</building>
        <room>22</room>
    </employee>
</employees>
EOT

first_name = 'Sandra'
last_name = 'Defoe'
node = doc.at("//employee[firstname/text()='%s' and lastname/text()='%s']" % [first_name, last_name])
node.at('building').content = '320'
node.at('room').content = '99'
```

Which results in:

```
doc.to_xml
# => "\uFEFF<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>\n" +
#    "<employees>\n" +
#    "    <employee id=\"be130\">\n" +
#    "        <firstname>William</firstname>\n" +
#    "        <lastname>Defoe</lastname>\n" +
#    "        <building>326</building>\n" +
#    "        <room>14a</room>\n" +
#    "    </employee>\n" +
#    "    <employee id=\"be132\">\n" +
#    "        <firstname>Sandra</firstname>\n" +
#    "        <lastname>Defoe</lastname>\n" +
#    "        <building>320</building>\n" +
#    "        <room>99</room>\n" +
#    "    </employee>\n" +
#    "</employees>\n"
```

Normally I recommend using CSS selectors because they tend to result in less visual noise, however CSS doesn't let us peek into the text of nodes, and working around that, while possible, results in even more noise. XPath, on the other hand, can be very noisy, but for this sort of task, it's more usable.

XPath is very well documented and figuring out what this is doing should be pretty easy.

The Ruby side of it is using a "[format string](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-25)":

```
"//employee[firstname/text()='%s' and lastname/text()='%s']" % [first_name, last_name])
```

similar to

```
"%s %s" % [first_name, last_name] # => "Sandra Defoe"
```

```
"//employee[firstname/text()='%s' and lastname/text()='%s']" % [first_name, last_name] 
# => "//employee[firstname/text()='Sandra' and lastname/text()='Defoe']"
```

Just for thoroughness, here's what I'd do if I wanted to use CSS exclusively:

```
node = doc.search('employee').find { |node| 
  node.at('firstname').text == first_name && node.at('lastname').text == last_name
}
```

This gets ugly though, because `search` tells Nokogiri to retrieve all `employee` nodes from libXML, then Ruby has to walk through them all telling Nokogiri to tell libXML to look in the child `firstname` and `lastname` nodes and return their text. That's slow, especially if there are many `employee` nodes and the one you want is at the bottom of the file.

The XPath selector tells Nokogiri to pass the search to libXML which parses it, finds the `employee` node with the child nodes containing the first and last names and returns only that node. It's much faster.

Note that `at('employee')` is equivalent to `search('employee').first`.

> ```
>    # File 'lib/nokogiri/xml/searchable.rb', line 70
>
>    def at(*args)
>      search(*args).first
>    end
> ```

Finally, mediate on the difference between a [NodeSet#text](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html#inner_text-instance_method) and [Node#text](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#content-instance_method) as the first will lead to insanity.